# What is the precise definition of a quadratic form of Minkowski type (in the infinite case)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, linear-algebra

I've been trying to understand a construction in the paper ["Degree Growth of Meromorphic Surface Maps"](http://sebastien.boucksom.perso.math.cnrs.fr/publis/BFJ_degree.pdf) by Bouksom, Favre and Jonsson. In it they state,

> In fact, the completion can be characterized by the following universal property:
>   if $(Y, q)$ is a complete topological vector space with a continuous nondegenerate
>   quadratic form of Minkowski type, any isometry $T : C(X) → Y$ continuously
>   extends to $L^2(X) → Y$ .

I don't know what a quadratic form of Minkowski type on an infinite dimensional vector space is. I was wondering if anyone knew of a reference for this?